# cronjob doesn't execute script correctly

Tags: ruby, sh

On a local server (ubuntu) I have installed the program foodsoft, which is written in ruby. It uses bundler, mysql too.
foodsoft can be started by the command

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails s -b 192.168.0.15
```

I also have programed a sh script, which starts foodsoft if it doesn't run:

```
#!/bin/sh
export DISPLAY=:0
export LANG=de_DE.utf8
ip_adr=$(/bin/hostname -I)
if [ $(pidof ruby) ]
then
echo "online"
else
echo "offline"
cd /home/jondal/foodsoft
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails s -b $ip_adr
fi
```

If I run the script in the shell, all works fine. But my cronjob (listed in crontab) doesn't execute the script completly. It produces the following txt file:

```
offline
bundler: command not found: rails
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

If I start the sh script in the shell with the prefix env -i I get the following:

> offline
>   /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/share/rubygems-integration/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle (LoadError)
>       from /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in`'

Do you have any ideas what I can do?

Comment: Are you using rvm?  You may need to take some extra steps to make rvm play nice with crontab.

Comment: Does your `cron` user have permissions in the `/home/jondal/foodsoft` directory?  Specifically, are execute permissions right, especially in `bin/`?

Answer (score 0):

That's hard to tell, but your diagnostic by running `env -i` may be biaised, `env -i` will probably give you a nice `$PATH`, but the `$PATH` in the crontab are way more minimalistic, quoting `man 5 crontab`:

> PATH  is  set  to  "/usr/bin:/bin".

So you may put:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

at the top of your `crontab`, as `man 5 crontab` gives you in the `EXAMPLE` section, and try again. But that does not explain how `bundle` is found with a minimalistic PATH, is `bundle` in /usr/bin ?

Are you using your own `crontab` ? If so, the only thing changing is the environment, if PATH is not enough, I encourage you to compare your env and the crontab env by putting an `env > /tmp/my.env` in your crontab, you may see something interesting.